# Can I use .Net Entity Framework for joining a db table with some other data source?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Is there a way to override entity framework mapping in such a way, that part of my entity graph would be coming from some external data source (file, web service call etc.)?

For example, let's say I have the following entities:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public ICollection Annotations {get;set;}
}

public class Annotation
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Text {get;set;}
}
```

And I want Product be loaded from dbo.Product table, and Annotation be loaded from CSV file?

Answer (score 0):

You can attach entities which were created using whatever back-channel you like to the DbContext using DbSet.Attach.  Read about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj592676

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I implemented custom IDbSet, hydrating collection of entities from a file, and exposed it from my DbContext (following this blog post http://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/?p=2827). However, I am still seeing that context constructs SQL joins when db-based entity references file-based entity in the linq query. I am trying to figure out how to make it ignore non-db entity for sql purposes.

Comment: Okay, I wasn't clear that the non-db entities are in fact not in the db at all.  I think you are probably not going to find what you're looking for in EF.  Why exactly do you want items that are not in the DB at all to be in the DbSet?

Comment: I am trying to expose EDM model to OData queries using Web Api controllers, and I was wondering if it was possible to integrate some non-DB feeds into the same model.